# googleOneTap not being triggered on button click as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-one-tap

I have the following button

```
 <Button onClick={handleGoogle}>Google Sign Up</Button>
```

And the function handleGoogle does the following

```
 function handleGoogle() {
    const options = {
      client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    };
    googleOneTap(options, (response) => {
      // Send response to server
      console.log("googleonetap-triggered");
      console.log(response);
    });
    console.log("handle google");
  }
```

However when I click the button I only see the console log 'handle google' , the 'googleonetap-triggered' is not logging, which means googleOneTap is not being triggerd.

Read multiple threads about this and cannot find a solution. Appreciate any help with this

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example using https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: Hi Heres the codesnandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/gracious-estrela-h2z7vz - the client id is obviously a dummy id